How to view the springboot logs stored on s3 bucket using loki promtail EKS
After enabling the loki on EKS with S3 storage, the folders (fake,index,loki_cluster_seed.json) are created inside the s3 bucket .
s3_bucket_folder
What this each folder consists & how the logs are stored as chunks to s3 bucket & how to view the logs inside s3 bucket or else how to convert it to human readable format?
I have already added the datasource on the grafana & i am getting the logs of each pod on different namespace level. My only problem is for how many hours the logs will be shown lively. If i want the previous 1 month logs to view, whether it is visible. Is there any option to save the old logs onto to storage?
